# Tableaux truth tree -only binary trees?

Tags: logic

Is it possible to use generic trees?
For example,  given the following formulae:

notC or notF or E

L or F or notE

F

I want to check if this KnowledgeBase is coherent.
Is it correct to use 3 branches for each node? Every node(excluding the leafs) has 3 children
All examples I've seen on the web use binary trees. Is this a rule or it is just memory optimization?

.....................F............

.....notC...........notF.........E

.L....F...notE.............L.....F.....notE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use more than 2 branches from a node.